# Facebook graph json output

Tags: json, facebook, graph

Here is what I get:

```
{
"data": [
{
"name": "company name",
"id": "123456789123456"
}
],
"paging": {
"cursors": {
 "before": "MAZDZD",
"after": "MAZDZD"
}
}
}
```

How do I get the id?
I have tried $content->data[0]->id but no luck ($content is the json array)

Comment: `$content->data[0]->id` should do the trick. What does `print_r($content)` show?

Comment: The above is the output from print_r($content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `print_r($content)` is outputting exactly that, you haven't decoded the JSON into something PHP can understand.

`$content = json_decode($content);`

Comment: That was it.  I have only dealt with json a few times.  :) thanks!